# What is differnces between GetService from ApplicationServices and IServiceProvider?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I see a code  which  resolve its needed service form `ApplicationServices` in two different ways:

```
public Foo(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
   _serviceProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceProvider>();
   _firstNeededDependancy = _serviceProvider.GetService<IFirstDependency>();
```

and for other dependency like `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger` use `ApplicationServices.GetService`

```
 public Foo(IApplicationBuilder app)
 {
    _logger = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILogger<BusSubscriber>>();
```

why for  `_firstNeededDependancy` it first resolve `IServiceProvider` and then using it for resolving 
`IFirstDependency` instead of for example `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IFirstDependency>();`,
are there any differences?

Comment: None. `ApplicationServices` is `IServiceProvider`. That looks like and preference of who ever wrote that code.

Comment: @Nkosi so they may not have any reason for doing like this on same `Constuctor`?